# Apache Camel's sql consumer: how to pass a parameter to query?

Tags: apache-camel

Suppose I have a route:

```
<route>
<from uri="sql:select orderid from Orders where date = '20140606'"/>
<split>
<simple>${body}</simple>
<process ref="orderProcessor"/>
</split>
</route>
```

This will give me orders for date 20140606 as a List. List will be splitted and each order will be processed by orderProcessor.

BUT, I would like to inject the date into the sql query, smth like

```
select orderid from Orders where date = '${date:now:YYYYMMDD}'
```

So that means every day when I start my application the date is changed automatically.

To my surprise I found out that this is not possible for "sql" endpoint when it is used as Consumer. I can pass parameter as a header if sql is used as Producer, but not as Consumer. Or am I wrong and this is possible?

BTW, I would prefere to use "sql" as consumer because it conveniently allows to execute and update query on each row retrieved using option "consumer.onConsume" (see: https://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html).

Comment: So you don't want it to be dynamic, just set at application startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The consumer endpoint (`from`) is static, that's why `${date:now:yyyyMMdd}` doesn't work.

Use the Java DSL, where you have all the flexibility:

```
String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
from("sql:select orderid from Orders where date = '" + today + '")
    .split(...);
```

Or use a producer endpoint (`to`):

```
<from uri="direct:start" />
<setHeader headerName="today"><simple>${date:now:yyyyMMdd}</simple></setHeader>
<to uri="sql:select orderid from Orders where date = :#today" />
<split>
    <simple>${body}</simple>
    <process ref="orderProcessor"/>
</split>
```

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you could DB specific date functions. Using Oracle DB this would be something like:

```
<from uri="sql:select orderid from Orders where date = to_date(to_char(current_date),'dd-mon-yy')" />
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using second solution. Just thought if that was the only solution. Would really prefer using sql asconsumer and using xml dsl.

Comment: @kachanov See my Oracle DB example as additional option.